# Back Button Skipping Page in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, back

I have found many generic posts suggesting this has to do with redirects.  I believe this may be due to how I have a form set up.

On the `plans.html.erb` page I have a form with four submits, each going to the same place with different params:

```
<%= form_with url: :affiliate_select_plan, class: "mx-auto" do |f|  %>

    <!-- Paid Plans -->
    <% @plans.each_with_index do |plan, i| %>
        <%= f.button 'Select Plan', value: plan[:name], type: 'submit' %> 

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have the `affiliate_select_plan_path` setup in my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :affiliate do
  post 'affiliate/select_plan', :to => 'affiliates/registrations#select_plan'
end
```

The form successfully hits the `select_plan` method in the controller, which redirects it to the `new_affiliate_registration_path`, passing the needed params.

```
def select_plan
    redirect_to new_affiliate_registration_path(plan: plan_params[:button])
end
```

The `new` method in the controller is called, directing the user to the sign up page:

```
# GET /resource/sign_up
def new
    @plan = AffiliatePlan.find_by(nickname: params.permit(:plan)[:plan].downcase)
    super
end
```

From this page, if the back button on the browser is selected, it will bring the user back to the page they were at before being at `plans.html.erb`.

Could this be related to the `redirect_to`?

---

### EDIT:

Here are the logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-25 19:06:02 -0500
Processing by Affiliates::RegistrationsController#plans as HTML
  Rendering affiliates/registrations/plans.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered affiliates/registrations/plans.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.5ms)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 195ms (Views: 194.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/partner/select_plan" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-25 19:06:13 -0500
Processing by Affiliates::RegistrationsController#select_plan as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ck8HGRryriXleQrUjCSKjTrIRLIw273EdSu4WZnFn3kAL1mMmk7jqR1tZgnPniHsMzHFMl81vPBRuvA0/W4uSw==", "button"=>"Local"}
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/partners/sign_up?plan=Local
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/partners/sign_up?plan=Local" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-25 19:06:13 -0500
Processing by Affiliates::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"plan"=>"Local"}
  AffiliatePlan Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "affiliate_plans".* FROM "affiliate_plans" WHERE "affiliate_plans"."nickname" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["nickname", "local"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/affiliates/registrations_controller.rb:11
  Rendering affiliates/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered affiliates/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (1.1ms)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 191ms (Views: 187.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: you are getting redirected to plans.html.erb page on browser back click. is this your issue or anything else?

Comment: @GaneshkumarK No, the problem is that they aren't being brought back to the plans.html.erb.  They are being brought to whatever page they were at prior to being at plans.html.erb

Comment: Do you have any callbacks prior to your `plans#index` action that might trigger a ridrection to whatever page was before ?

Comment: @VincentRolea The `plans` action is in the `Affiliates::RegistrationsController`. Right now it is set as the root `root to: "affiliates/registrations#plans"` (within the devise affiliate scope).   There's no callbacks setup that should trigger a redirection that I can think of.  It will even redirect off the site if they were previously at an external page.

Comment: Could you share your logs from the plan selection to the back-button hit ?

Comment: What is your controller extending from that you haver to call `super` in the new action?

Comment: @VincentRolea Just added them to the question.  Thanks for suggesting that, it seems there may be a redirect by Devise.  Looking further into that

Comment: @bwalshy It's the Devise RegistrationsController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hunch that this might have to do with form resubmission: Forms and the back button tend to be a bit wonky at times.

However, instead of going more in depth with this, let me point you in another direction. I'm doing this because to me, this looks like a classic case of someone trying to find a solution to the wrong problem. I'm saying this because based on the code and log snippets you've provided, you're jumping through hoops to pass a parameter (in your case the name of a plan) via multiple actions – which, if I'm right, is just unnecessary.

Here's what I would do instead:

```
<% @plans.each do |plan| %>
  <%=
    link_to 'Select Plan',
    new_affiliate_registration_path(plan: plan.downcase),
    class: 'some-button-class
  %>
<% end %>
```

This way, you don't have to mess around in your controllers in any way. Also, since there is no POST request, you won't have any issues with form (re)population and such things.